# Checking asynchronous methods have finished in a destructor

Tags: c++, asynchronous

I have a class that currently looks like this (pseudo-pseudo-code):

```
class AsyncStore {
public:
  AsyncStore();
  ~AsyncStore() {
    // Make sure writes have flushed somehow
  }

  void write_something() {
    // Issue an asynchronous write, and return immediately
  }

  void sync_writes() {
    // Check all writes could be flushed, and throw if any failed
  }
};
```

This has the problem that the destructor has no way of signalling an error (we can't throw, and we can't signal there's an error in any other way).

Ideally, users of this class would call `sync_writes()` before the destructor is called, and handle any exceptions thrown, so that at destruction time, there's nothing to do.

As it stands, there's no way to enforce this. It feels like this must be a relatively common problem - is there a way for handling this such that I can guarantee there are no writes pending at destruction time?

Comment: "we can't signal there's an error in any other way". Says who?

Comment: How would you signal an error in a destructor? You can't throw or return an error status.

Comment: There are lots of way to signal an error. You can log a message to a file, or push a value to a log container to be processed later somewhere. It depends on who is supposed to receive your signal.

Comment: @n.m. of course that's possible, but architecturally undesirable. They rely on shared/global state. Reminds of GetLastError.

Comment: Logs are global, but I fail to see how this makes them similar to GetLastError. Anyway, you are right that there's a genuine architectural problem. You are wrong if you expect it to have an easy solution with no shortcomings. The problem is not specific to C++, destructors or exceptions by the way.

Comment: I'm happy with shortcomings - I get that this is not trivially solvable. I'm interested in seeing a few solutions, and seeing if any have acceptable shortcomings.

Comment: Suppose there are no classes, destructors, or exceptions, just plain old C-style procedural stuff. Function X opens file A, then calls function Y that opens file B, does something, then closes B. B cannot close because of an I/O error. Y returns an error code, and X needs to propagate it upstream. X starts cleaning up after itself, tries to close file A... and it cannot close because of a different kind of I/O error. Now X has two different errors to return at once. What exactly has changed with the advent of destructors and RAII?

Answer (score 1):

You could just force the API consumer to call `sync_writes` before destroying the object. If the destructor is entered with work outstanding, `terminate()`, or do some other emergency action (like just not waiting for the work and logging an error).

I think this is an API design problem. Just decide that callers have to correctly shut down the object and enforce it at runtime. If callers violate the API contract they cannot expect correct results.

There's an alternative: Force the API consumer to register a callback that gets called in case of errors. The callback could be accepted in the constructor.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions - I think the former approach might end up being the best option. The problem with the latter is that people might bind it to a member function on a class whose lifetime is bound to the lifetime of AsyncStore.

Comment: In the case that there are shared assets, such as ports, files or buffers, another possibility is to use a `shared_ptr` to the asset.  In particular look at [`std::enable_shared_from_this`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this) to see if it might be applicable to your situation.

Comment: This is shifting the problem, not solving it. So you throw RAII out of the window and force everyone to call the close method explicitly, fine. Now what happens if you need to shut down your object due to stack unwinding when an exception is thrown?

Comment: That's a good point. I guess any shutdown method that requires caller cooperation is no good. Bad situation. I guess this forces the callback method or some other inelegant solution.